# Best Image compression library

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, image-uploading, image-compression

I am working on a project in which I need to store user profile images and show user images to them. I am using Google FireStore as database. I want to upload user image, but as we know their image size is too big, it can fill my storage very quickly, so I want to store image as like WhatsApp is doing.

Comment: use image compressor

Answer (score 3):

For Image crop, I suggest UCrop Library
https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/issues

For Compres I suggest:
https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

Answer (score 1):

UCrop is best but it provides you with its own default UI. You have to modify it.

For simplicity, I prefer

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

And if you want to crop in circle then use cropiwa

https://github.com/steelkiwi/cropiwa

For Compressing image, Compressor is best which is suggested by Dhaval.

https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor